# Typo3 Extension missing index.php

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I installed two new extensions (formhandler & dix_urltool) in a new typo3 6.2.6 install. But in the backend when I click on the extension I'm getting an typo3 page error with the message "Page Not Found Reason: File "index.php" was not found (2)!"

Are these extensions need some manual setting up?

Comment: Which extension is causing the error? You named two. What exactly do you mean by "when I click on the extension"?

Comment: The dix_urltool is generating the error.

Comment: Do you have the most recent version installed? Did you click on a backend module of this extension?

Comment: @Tom I am getting the same error with direct_mail. Did you locate the cause?

Comment: @Urs after a Typo3 upgrade the problem is solved. But I never new what caused it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on 6.2.14, so it must be a server issue